# How to play streaming background audio in Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: audio, streaming, windows-phone, windows-phone-7

I've seen a tutorial about how to play local files using a background agent in WP7 Mango but it specifically states that the tutorial is related to local files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978(v=VS.92).aspx

Does a similar tutorial exist for streaming files from the web?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used the same tutorial, and it works fine if you want to play something like a podcast that is stored as an mp3 file on a webserver. You just set an absolute Uri in the audiotrack.

I don't think you need to use the specific Streaming project unless you are doing live streaming.