# Async copy a audio stream in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio-streaming

I have a working audio player implemented in WP7 that get the audio stream online with a HttpWebRequest and uses an AudioStreamingAgent and a MediaStreamSource to play it on the background.

The code to fetch the stream is the following:

```
public class AudioTrackStreamer : AudioStreamingAgent 
{
    protected override void OnBeginStreaming(AudioTrack track, AudioStreamer streamer)
    {
        stream = GetDownloadStream(track.Tag);

        // Use sine wave audio generator to simulate a streaming audio feed
        BackgroundMp3MediaStreamSource mss = new BackgroundMp3MediaStreamSource(stream);

        // Event handler for when a track is complete or the user switches tracks
        mss.StreamingCompleted += new EventHandler(mss_StreamingCompleted);

        // Set the source
        streamer.SetSource((MediaStreamSource) mss);
    }
}
```

I need to change the client to fetch an AES encoded stream and decode it before playing it.

I though that I could create a decoded stream and pass it to the BackgroundMp3MediaStreamSource. Something like:

```
...
stream = GetDownloadStream(track.Tag);
decodedStream = GetDecodedStream(stream);
BackgroundMp3MediaStreamSource mss = new BackgroundMp3MediaStreamSource(decodedStream);
...


private Stream GetDecodedStream(Stream encoded) {
    Stream destination = new MemoryStream();
    BackgroundWorker streamCopier = new BackgroundWorker();
    streamCopier.DoWork += (o, e) => StreamCopierDoWork(encoded, destination);
    streamCopier.RunWorkerAsync();

    return new NonUiStreamer(destination);
}

private static void StreamCopierDoWork(Stream encoded, Stream destination) {
    const int chunk = 1 * 1024;

    var buffer = new byte[chunk];

    AsyncCallback rc = null;
    rc = readResult => {
        int read = encoded.EndRead(readResult);
        if (read > 0) {
            destination.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, read, writeResult => {
                    destination.EndWrite(writeResult);
                    encoded.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, rc, null);
            }, null);
        }
    };
    encoded.BeginRead(buffer, 0, chunk, rc, null);
}
```

**Note**: I'm not decoding the stream yet. Just copying it asynchronously to another stream to see if everything works.

But when I try to read the first bytes of the decoded stream `decodedStream.Read(data, 0, 3);` it returns 0 bytes.

Why can't I read the decodedStream?

Comment: Hi, Daniel. I'm trying to implement a background live-stream audio player http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111300/how-to-play-streaming-background-audio-in-windows-phone-7-5. Can you, please, provide me how to do it? I mean the code. I  looked for any example, but I couldn't find any right one.

Comment: @AlexMaslakov, you can get a good example here: https://github.com/loarabia/ManagedMediaHelpers but I was only able to play mp3 with the following specs: MPEG Version 1, 320000 Bit Rate and 44100 Sampling Rate

Comment: Why does it play mp3 with the certain specs only?

Comment: @AlexMaslakov I think the Mpeg Frame on that solution don't support certain specs. I didn't try all the possible specs, but at least it didn't play when I choose a MPEG2 with 64000 bit rate and 22050 sampling rate.

Comment: @Daniel: Hi Daniel, Can You Please See My Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177334/play-online-audio-stream-in-wp7-on-the-fly